# posting data from c# to web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I understand how to send data from C# to webpage. However, in Asp.net how do i retrieve the post data.

This is my class for sending data to webpage

What is the variable should i put here. Request.Query[""]

```
class PostData
{
    private WebRequest request;
    private Stream dataStream;

    public PostData(String url)
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    }

    public bool PostDataToWeb(String data)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-formurlencoded";
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        return true;
    }

}
```

My webpage class ---> this is a cshtml file in webmatrix

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "CMS Home Page";
    if(IsPost)
    {
        //whats the input am i supposed to input here? 
        String a = Request.Form[""];
    }
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Comment: try using `GET`method

Comment: Question is not clear. You mean, how to read data posted back to your app?

Comment: How do i get the value i posted into the variable a

Comment: you need to explore the Request object. it may not be in the querystring but instead, in the Form collection... so if you are posting to your cshtml page, then check the Request.Form["TheKeyHere"]

Comment: Are you using POST when you should be using GET? AFAIK GET is the method that posts form variables to a querystring...

Comment: You should use GET method to retrieve data from code behind.

Comment: i am not too sure whats the way to obtain data as i could only google the first part out.

Comment: Your webpage class looks as of ASP.NET MVC. In this case to obtain values that came by POST http query you need to provide your controller action with [HttpPost] attribute as well as with the proper viewmodel (a parameter(s) of action method) or read values directly from HttpContext.Request.Form that is accessible from inside of action body.

Comment: Sorry i didnt really get you. Could you give an example

Comment: @aceminer first please clarify what technology you wanna use: ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC or C# WinForms? Your code doesnt give me understanding for that..

Comment: I am sending data from C# winForms to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: These are different kind of applications and i can't realize why you're doing it... You can't "send data from C# to webpage", the webpage in MVC is a result or rendering a Razor template (cshtml) with values returned by MVC controller action. Or i'm missing something..

Comment: Apparently it seems there was an ability to do that which is where i got the first section of my code from. but as for the second portion i am not too sure how to write it

Comment: I'm not sure for i can help more...